# How to create a drawable that's square on the outside and has rounded corners inside?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create rounded corners on a MapView, and since there doesn't seem to be any way to do it by default, I'm basically overlaying a layout with a background over my map view, like so:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/panel_rounded_corner_transparent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My rounded corner drawable is defined like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/bg_rounded_corner_transparent" />
</selector>
```

and the drawable inside is defined as:

```
<layer-list
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape>

      <solid
        android:color="@color/transparent" />
      <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/darkgray" />
      <corners
        android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

However, the problem is that since the map ends up rectangular and the border is rounded, the corners of the map peek out from behind the corners of my makeshift border. How do I set a background color for only the outside of my border, while keeping the inside of the panel transparent?

To clarify, here are some screenshots.

This screenshot shows the map as originally "bounded" by the overlaid border:

[image]

This screenshot replaces the map with a red background, for greater clarity in seeing what the problem is:

[image]

As you can see, the red (and by extension, the map) bleeds outside the border.

I can add a 1dp padding to the map, but that doesn't entirely solve the issue as you can see here:

[image]

Since the corners are rounded, part of the map still leaks out. It's a lot better than the first option, but not perfect--there are 1 pixel dots at the corners.

As this screenshot shows, a padding of more than 1dp is not a solution since it creates another problem entirely:

[image]

Comment: can you post a screenshot of it?

Comment: Use padding. So the map view will stay inside your bounds

Comment: Updated the post with some photographs. Blessenm, I thought of your suggestion pretty soon after I posted the original question, but it doesn't entirely resolve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try extending the MapView like the following:

```
private class MyMapView extends MapView {

    public MyMapView(Context context, String apiKey) {
        super(context, apiKey);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Path path = new Path();
        RectF r = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight()); 
        path.addRoundRect(r, 12, 12, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(path);
        super.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

You might need to adjust the radius for [path.addRoundRect()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#addRoundRect%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Path.Direction%29)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the styleable elements?  Take a look at this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#DrawableCorners_bottomLeftRadius

Hope this helps, this should solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

hi there i play around for a few hours with this and here is my solution for a ImageView with transparent frame (oval) inside and solid color outside. I know it is a oval shape but it also works with rect.

Implement a FrameLayout with two children inside. So the shape will overlapping the ImageView:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/testLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mainContentImage"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_circle">
        </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

here is the shape_circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_circle_rect"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_circle_oval"/>
</layer-list>
```

shape_circle_rect.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <padding 
        android:left="-70dp"
        android:top="-70dp"
        android:right="-70dp"
        android:bottom="-70dp"/>

</shape>
```

shape_circle_oval.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
    <stroke android:color="#ffffff" android:width="70dp"/>
</shape>
```

its not *exactly* what you searching for but it could help.

Answer (score 0):

hope this is woking........read abount styles and other part of developers

may help you

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html

Comment: How does the link help? Mine to broaden your answer?